# Discord py - menu with variables from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to create a command that outputs five different memes with the help of a menu. You should then be able to go back and forth with the arrow keys.

[image: Like this]

Like this, but with arrow buttons below.

[image]

So far I have saved the variables for creating the meme in a dictionary. But I don't know how to call it up so that the menu understands it correctly.

My Code:

```py
import discord
import aiohttp

from discord.ext import commands, menus

class Test:
    def __init__(self, key, value):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value

class Source(menus.GroupByPageSource):
    async def format_page(self, menu, entry):
        offset = ((menu.current_page) * 5) + 1
        joined = '\n'.join(f'• ``{v.value}``' for i, v in enumerate(entry.items, offset))

        embed = discord.Embed(title=entry.key, description=joined, color=0xf7fcfd)
        embed.set_author(name=f"Page: {menu.current_page + 1}/{self.get_max_pages()}")

        return embed

class Reddit(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def info(self, ctx):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get("https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme/5") as resp:

                memes = await resp.json()
                all_memes = {}
                count = 0

                for meme in memes["memes"]:

                    count += 1

                    await ctx.trigger_typing()
                    if meme["nsfw"] == True:
                        return True

                    all_memes[count] = {
                        "link": meme["postLink"],
                        "reddit": meme["subreddit"],
                        "title": meme["title"],
                        "author": meme["author"], 
                        "upvotes": meme["ups"], 
                        "nsfw": meme["nsfw"],
                        "image": meme["preview"][-1]
                    }

                data = [
                    Test(key=key, value=value)
                    for key in ["NONE"]
                    for value in all_memes.values()
                ]

                pages = menus.MenuPages(
                    source=Source(data, key=lambda t: t.key, per_page=1),
                    clear_reactions_after=True
                )

                return await pages.start(ctx)
                     

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Reddit(client))
```

If I call the command now, the output looks like this:

[image]

It should create an embed like this:

```py
embed = discord.Embed(description=f"[{title}]({link})", color=0xf7fcfd)
embed.set_author(name=f'u/{reddit}')
embed.add_field(name="Author:", value=author)
embed.add_field(name="Upvotes:", value=upvotes)
embed.set_image(url=image)
embed.set_footer(
    text=f"Requested by {ctx.author} | Response time : {round(self.client.latency * 1000)} ms",
    icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url,
)

await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class DisplayPages(Menu):
    def __init__(self, pages, timeout: int = 180):
        super().__init__(timeout=timeout, clear_reactions_after=True)

        self.current = 0

        self.pages = pages

    async def send_initial_message(self, _, destination):
        current = self.pages[self.current]

        if isinstance(current, discord.Embed):
            return await destination.send(embed=current)

        return await destination.send(current)

    async def update_index(self, payload, index_change):
        self.current = max(0, min(len(self.pages) - 1, self.current + index_change))

    async def on_reaction(self, payload, index_change):
        await self.update_index(payload, index_change)

        current = self.pages[self.current]

        if isinstance(current, discord.Embed):
            return await self.message.edit(content=None, embed=current)

        await self.message.edit(content=current, embed=None)

    @menus.button(Reacts.REWIND)
    async def go_first(self, payload):
        await self.on_reaction(payload, -self.current)

    @menus.button(Reacts.ARROW_LEFT)
    async def go_prev(self, payload):
        await self.on_reaction(payload, -1)

    @menus.button(Reacts.ARROW_RIGHT)
    async def go_next(self, payload):
        await self.on_reaction(payload, 1)

    @menus.button(Reacts.FAST_FORWARD)
    async def go_last(self, payload):
        await self.on_reaction(payload, len(self.pages) - self.current - 1)
```

This is my old base class for menus with 4 buttons for what you want. Works quite simply by editing the message after each button press with a new embed/message.

Comment: can you give me an example, where you use it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `AutoEmbedPaginator` or `CustomEmbedPaginator` class of [DiscordUtils](https://pypi.org/project/DiscordUtils/)

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Not what I was looking for, but an awesome alternativ.